# Error while converting Mercurial to Git

Tags: git, mercurial, repository

I want to convert a Mercurial Repo to GitHub's repo.
I found many answers here But none of them work for me.

The major answer is:

```
cd ~
git clone git://repo.or.cz/fast-export.git
git init git_repo
cd git_repo
~/fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r /path/to/old/mercurial_repo
git checkout HEAD
```

However, when I try this in my Git Shell, the following error occurs:

```
D:\GitHub\odk-aggregate [master]> C:/Users/Adhish/fast-export/hg-fast-export -r D:\Development\opendatakit.aggregate
C:/Users/Adhish/fast-export/hg-fast-export : The term 'C:/Users/Adhish/fast-export/hg-fast-export' is not recognized
as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ C:/Users/Adhish/fast-export/hg-fast-export -r D:\Development\opendatakit.aggrega ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:/Users/Adhish.../hg-fast-export:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

D:\GitHub\odk-aggregate [master]>
```

Please let me know where am I going wrong.

**EDIT:**

When I change the command to fast-export.**SH**, nothing happens.

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Have you downloaded `fast-export`?

Comment: Yes.. I have.. No idea why it isn't running

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to execute the commands via `cmd` or `powershell`, am I right? You are on windows?

Comment: Yes.. PowerShell in Windows 8.1

Comment: I think that's the issue, try it using git bash.

Comment: Yes.. Used it already.. No success.

Comment: "No success", what exactly happend and what was the error?

Comment: The same error... As posted in the question..

Comment: Then you didn't use git bash, the error is typical for a windows shell, a unix like bash would have looked different. You have to use **Git Bash** not your usual windows git shell.

Comment: Oh okay ..sorry. My bad. Will try..